# Print the value fetched from javascript script in php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, gtag.js

I use following way to fetch the value of gtag if it already exists in the code:

```
        <script>
        const regex = /googletagmanager\.com\/gtag\/js\?id=([^\s'"]+)/gi;

        const scriptTags = document.querySelectorAll('script');
                let trackingID = ''; 
                scriptTags.forEach(script => {
                    const src = script.getAttribute('src');
                     if (src && src.includes('googletagmanager.com/gtag/js')) {
                        const match = regex.exec(src);
                     if (match && match.length > 1) {
                        trackingID = match[1];
                     }
                   }
                });
        </script>
```

Now I want the **trackingID** to be printed in the following script if it exists else print the code value that exists

```
<script async src="<?php echo ( $local_analytics_file ?? 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=' ) . '?' . esc_html( $UA_CODE ); ?>"></script>
```

Need something like

```
<script async src="<?php echo ( $local_analytics_file ?? 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=+if(trackingID) trackingID' ) . '?' . esc_html( $UA_CODE ); ?>"></script>
```

And similarly in following

```
<script>
            console.log('Google Analytics Tracking ID:', trackingID);

            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());

            const configuration = JSON.parse( '<?php echo $configuration; ?>' );
            const gaID = '<?php echo esc_html( $UA_CODE ); ?>'; // I want trackingID to be printed if available else print the $UA_CODE
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using JavaScript to look for other JavaScript on the page that represents Google Analytics (or GTM or whatever), and then writing more JavaScript to represent the same thing? This feels very overly complicated.

Comment: In same page there is a gtag of some other one. I want to use that gtag value inside my own tracking gtag so that there is no tracking conflict